# In flutter, how to shift content for navigation drawer instead of it overlaying on top.

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-animation

I want something that should look like this.
[The content moving aside for the nav drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IdYj.gif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a custom `Drawer`, the regular `Drawer` doesn't support that functionality. You also cannot use the `drawer` property of `Scaffold`. You would have to make a completely dynamic page.

In this video tutorial Fluttery creates a completely custom `Drawer`, so you might wanna have a look at it for some instructions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CEjnCVdgRM&t=7s

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into it. Seems like exactly what I needed.

Comment: @KhaledAli unfortunately, Fluttery took down all of his videos. Maybe this helps you? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzuHfHyJcuI